# Why is curl storing my cookie in c:\

Tags: php, cookies, curl

I'm setting the curl cookiejar option with the following:

```php
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
```

this puts the file in c:\

I try to use an absolute path (c:\server\docs) and the script breaks. Even so, the cookie does get written to that path. Odd.

Is there another way I'm supposed to define the path to my webserver?

Comment: You are escaping your slashes right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
define("SITE_PATH",'c:\server\docs');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, SITE_PATH . "/cookie.txt");
```

I hope it helps

Thanks
:)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work either. Curious, why do you use a / in front of your cookie.txt? I've tried with /, and // and \\, and \ and nothing there and none of it works.

Comment: use var_dump(file_exists('c:\server\docs\cookie.txt')) and tell me what you have

Comment: bool(false) - is that what you want?

Comment: Yes that is what i expected .... your script is not working  because the files does not exist...  can you get the real file path

Comment: holy crap. I had to make a correction to the path and now I get bool(true). However, the script still does not log me in.

Comment: I posted the script earlier and got ridiculed so I'm not going to post it again. If I leave my cookie set to just plain "cookie.txt" my script logs me in. If I try to change it at all, it doesn't log me in. If you want to see the script it'll have to happen off stack overflow.

Comment: put it at pastebin or something .. send the link i"ll help you out  i'll help you out ...

Comment: Now i understand what you are trying to  .. you need to first get the cookies and right it to `cookies.txt` just like the way you have done for `__EVENTVALIDATION` see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/895786/how-to-get-the-cookies-from-a-php-curl-into-a-variable on getting cookie values

Comment: yeah, and that happens, as long as i define the location of cookies.txt as just cookies.txt. i wanted to change it because it was storing it on c:\. i cannot figure out how to store it in \tmp.

Comment: May be you don't have permission in that folder ... try a diffrent folder with no spaces or use `getcwd`

Comment: I'm sorry, I do not know how to use getcwd. I am on windows tho

Comment: That doesn't display any information. If it's creating the cookie.txt in whatever location I designate, doesn't that indicate it has at least some permission? I don't get why it writes the cookie but cuases the script to break.

Comment: Thanks .. hope i was able to help @KiloJKilo

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to change it to "`c:\\server\\docs\\`"

Comment: The script still breaks when I escape the slashes. But the cookie is still written to the directory I want.