# When running a production build of my react app, res.data returns html instead of a token

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jwt

When I was running a dev build on my computer locally, res.data would return the JWT token of the user when logging in. However, when I'm running a production build on my VPS, res.data returns this HTML:

```
<!doctype html><html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css"><link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet"><title>Fleet of Fury</title><link href="/static/css/main.2d62af7c.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head><body>
<noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
<div id="root"></div><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script><script>!function(l){function e(e){for(var r,t,n=e[0],o=e[1],u=e[2],f=0,i=[];f<n.length;f++)t=n[f],p[t]&&i.push(p[t][0]),p[t]=0;for(r in o)Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(o,r)&&(l[r]=o[r]);for(s&&s(e);i.length;)i.shift()();return c.push.apply(c,u||[]),a()}function a(){for(var e,r=0;r<c.length;r++){for(var t=c[r],n=!0,o=1;o<t.length;o++){var u=t[o];0!==p[u]&&(n=!1)}n&&(c.splice(r--,1),e=f(f.s=t[0]))}return e}var t={},p={2:0},c=[];function f(e){if(t[e])return t[e].exports;var r=t[e]={i:e,l:!1,exports:{}};return l[e].call(r.exports,r,r.exports,f),r.l=!0,r.exports}f.m=l,f.c=t,f.d=function(e,r,t){f.o(e,r)||Object.defineProperty(e,r,{enumerable:!0,get:t})},f.r=function(e){"undefined"!=typeof Symbol&&Symbol.toStringTag&&Object.defineProperty(e,Symbol.toStringTag,{value:"Module"}),Object.defineProperty(e,"__esModule",{value:!0})},f.t=function(r,e){if(1&e&&(r=f(r)),8&e)return r;if(4&e&&"object"==typeof r&&r&&r.__esModule)return r;var t=Object.create(null);if(f.r(t),Object.defineProperty(t,"default",{enumerable:!0,value:r}),2&e&&"string"!=typeof r)for(var n in r)f.d(t,n,function(e){return r[e]}.bind(null,n));return t},f.n=function(e){var r=e&&e.__esModule?function(){return e.default}:function(){return e};return f.d(r,"a",r),r},f.o=function(e,r){return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e,r)},f.p="/";var r=window.webpackJsonp=window.webpackJsonp||[],n=r.push.bind(r);r.push=e,r=r.slice();for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)e(r[o]);var s=n;a()}([])</script><script src="/static/js/1.83de47ce.chunk.js"></script><script src="/static/js/main.f9fff7cc.chunk.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Users.js:

```js
router.post("/register", (req, res) => {
  // Form validation

  const { errors, isValid } = validateRegisterInput(req.body);

  // Check validation
  if (!isValid) {
    return res.status(400).json(errors);
  }

  User.findOne({ name: req.body.name.toLowerCase() }).then(user => {
    if (user) {
      return res.status(400).json({ name: "Name already exists" });
    } else {
      const newUser = new User({
        name: req.body.name.toLowerCase(),
        password: req.body.password
      });

      // Hash password before saving in database
      bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
        bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
          if (err) throw err;
          newUser.password = hash;
          newUser
            .save()
            .then(user => res.json(user))
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
        });
      });
    }
  });
});

// @route POST api/users/login
// @desc Login user and return JWT token
// @access Public
router.post("/login", (req, res) => {
  // Form validation

  const { errors, isValid } = validateLoginInput(req.body);

  // Check validation
  if (!isValid) {
    return res.status(400).json(errors);
  }

  const name = req.body.name.toLowerCase();
  const password = req.body.password;

  // Find user by name
  User.findOne({ name }).then(user => {
    // Check if user exists
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(404).json({ namenotfound: "Name not found" });
    }
    if (user.name === "admin") {
      return res.status(404).json({ namenotfound: "Name not found" });
    }

    // Check password
    bcrypt.compare(password, user.password).then(isMatch => {
      if (isMatch) {
        // User matched
        // Create JWT Payload
        const payload = {
          id: user.id,
          name: user.name
        };

        // Sign token
        jwt.sign(
          payload,
          keys.secretOrKey,
          {
            expiresIn: 31556926 // 1 year in seconds
          },
          (err, token) => {
            res.json({
              success: true,
              token: "Bearer " + token
            });
          }
        );
      } else {
        return res
          .status(400)
          .json({ passwordincorrect: "Password incorrect" });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

authActions.js

```js
export const loginUser = userData => dispatch => {
  axios
    .post("/api/users/login", userData)
    .then(res => {
      // Save to localStorage

      // Set token to localStorage
      console.log(res.data)
      console.log(res.data.token)
      const { token } = res.data;
      localStorage.setItem("jwtToken", token);
      // Set token to Auth header
      setAuthToken(token);
      // Decode token to get user data
      const decoded = jwt_decode(token);
      // Set current user
      dispatch(setCurrentUser(decoded));
    })
    .catch(err =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_ERRORS,
        payload: ((err||{}).response||{}).data || 'Error unexpected'
      })
    );
};
```

This makes the JWT token in localStorage undefined and completely stops my app from registering users, logging in users, etc.

Any way to fix this?

(To build my project, I've been running react-scripts build and then using serve -s build -l 80 to host it on port 80)

Comment: Cloudflare config?  Possibly helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29569021/can-one-cache-and-secure-a-rest-api-with-cloudflare

Comment: How would that help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was wrong. I wasn't serving the static files made with react-scripts build.

```js
app.use(express.static('client/build'))

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
   res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'))
})
```