# Use php Curl to login into website and parse a restricted webpage

Tags: php, authentication, curl, cookies

I have been struggling a lot to make a script (for personal use) to login my chess.com account remotly, access my friends page and parse my friends list. Despite many tries, I am still stuck at the first step (login remotly to my account).

I have created a test account on chess.com for the purpose of this test code.
Username: "stackoverjohndoe"    Password: "stackoverjohndoepassword"

```
   
/The username or email address of the account.
define('USERNAME', 'stackoverjohndoe');

//The password of the account.
define('PASSWORD', 'stackoverjohndoepassword');

//The password of the account.
define('TPATH', 'https://www.chess.com/');

//The password of the account.
define('TOKEN', 'iwQZkjg8fnm9FhgLcjaOwxlB5MgSIYVTdW5vSkib2m');


//Set a user agent. This basically tells the server that we are using Chrome ;)
define('USER_AGENT', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.2309.372 Safari/537.36');

//Where our cookie information will be stored (needed for authentication).
define('COOKIE_FILE', 'cookie.txt');

//URL of the login form.
define('LOGIN_FORM_URL', 'https://www.chess.com/login_check');

//Login action URL. Sometimes, this is the same URL as the login form.
define('LOGIN_ACTION_URL', 'https://www.chess.com/login_check');


//An associative array that represents the required form fields.
//You will need to change the keys / index names to match the name of the form
//fields.
$postValues = array(
    '_username' => USERNAME,
    '_password' => PASSWORD,
    '_target_path' => TPATH,
    '_token' => TOKEN,
    'login' => ''

);
    

//Initiate cURL.
$curl = curl_init();

//Set the URL that we want to send our POST request to. In this
//case, it's the action URL of the login form.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.chess.com/login_check');

//Tell cURL that we want to carry out a POST request.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);

//Set our post fields / date (from the array above).
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postValues));

//We don't want any HTTPS errors.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

//Where our cookie details are saved. This is typically required
//for authentication, as the session ID is usually saved in the cookie file.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, COOKIE_FILE);

//Sets the user agent. Some websites will attempt to block bot user agents.
//Hence the reason I gave it a Chrome user agent.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, USER_AGENT);

//Tells cURL to return the output once the request has been executed.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

//Allows us to set the referer header. In this particular case, we are 
//fooling the server into thinking that we were referred by the login form.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://www.chess.com/login');

//Do we want to follow any redirects?
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);

//Execute the login request.
curl_exec($curl);

//Check for errors!
if(curl_errno($curl)){
    throw new Exception(curl_error($curl));
}

//We should be logged in by now. Let's attempt to access a password protected page
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.chess.com/home/friends');

//Use the same cookie file.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, COOKIE_FILE);

//Use the same user agent, just in case it is used by the server for session validation.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, USER_AGENT);

//We don't want any HTTPS / SSL errors.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

//Execute the GET request and print out the result.
echo curl_exec($curl);
```

Comment: You're using `username` and `password` as the POST parameters to `login_check`. These are not the parameters I see. I see: `_username`, `_password`, `login`, `_target_path` and `_token`.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the code with these parameters, however it still doesn't work. I am not sure what to do with `login`

Comment: `login` represents the submit button, and probably needs to be there even though its content is an empty string. The stumbling block here is probably the `_token`. I've noticed it changes all the time, and is probably there to prevent you from doing an automated login. You would need to retrieve a new `_token` before you log in.

Comment: Indeed the `_token` changes every few minutes; however even if i use a token currently valid, my code won't work. So it seems that there is at least one other issue if I'm not mistaking.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably true. I have no idea what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are you won't succeed, I'm afraid. Because chess.com, like a gazillion of other sites, is protected by Cloudflare:

```sh
$ curl --head https://www.chess.com
```

This yields:

```sh
...
set-cookie: __cfduid=...
cf-cache-status: ...
cf-request-id: ...
set-cookie: __cf_bm=...
server: cloudflare
cf-ray: 63ff9eb5db5b2c9d-LHR
...
```

These are either [Cloudflare headers](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170986-How-does-Cloudflare-handle-HTTP-Request-headers-), or [Cloudflare cookies](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170156-Understanding-the-Cloudflare-Cookies).

Now, if you'd acquire a valid token and try to login afterwards via `curl`, you'll be presented with Cloudflare's [Under Attack Mode](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170076-Understanding-Cloudflare-Under-Attack-mode-advanced-DDOS-protection-) page:

```html
<div class="cf-browser-verification cf-im-under-attack">
    <!-- ... -->
    <form class="challenge-form" id="challenge-form" action="/login_check?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=..." method="POST" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <!-- ... -->
    </form>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
        (function(){
            // ...
            cpo.src="/cdn-cgi/challenge-platform/h/b/orchestrate/jsch/v1?ray=63ff96d8a9b8070a";
            document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(cpo);
        }());
        //]]>
    </script>
</div>
```

One of the purposes of this page is to check whether or not you've JavaScript enabled, thus ruling out any attempts to login via `curl`.

Because Cloudflare also happens to be a moving target, past solutions to bypass its checks will most likely not work anymore, and attempts to analyze the techniques employed by Cloudflare might have become obsolete:

- [cURL - Load a site with CloudFlare protection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18500088/curl-load-a-site-with-cloudflare-protection)
- https://github.com/KyranRana/cloudflare-bypass
- https://github.com/yottaiq/CloudAttack (Python, JS)
- https://khromov.wordpress.com/2013/02/05/cloudflare-client-side-ddos-detection-how-does-it-work/
- https://blog.detectify.com/2019/07/31/bypassing-cloudflare-waf-with-the-origin-server-ip-address/

Comment: Thanks for the explaination.
When I log in to the account from a browser and copy a Curl cmd for any type of action, I appear to be able to execute this command remotely with a Curl without being blocked by Cloudflare. Does that mean Cloudflare only interfere at the "login step/page"?

Comment: You mean by using "Copy as cURL" from dev tools? You're already authenticated by then, and everything both chess.com & Cloudflare need to validate your request is given in the headers. So as long as nothing's invalidated, this should work, yes - though Cloudflare will still act as a proxy to chess.com on every single request.