# How Can I Make Curl Get The Cookies

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to get the cookies from a php curl into a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895786/how-to-get-the-cookies-from-a-php-curl-into-a-variable)

I have the code below running and what it does is get a web page using curl. My problem is when it gets the web page it doesnt get the cookies from the site.

```
   $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, ''.$stuff_link[0].'');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, false);
    $html = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close ( $ch );
    echo $html;
```

I tried a few thing none of which worked.

Comment: i seen that post and tired that it doesnt work

Comment: Please update the code to what your trying/using

Answer (score 6):

```
$ch = curl_init('http://www.google.com/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
// get headers too with this line
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
// get cookie, all cos sometime set-cookie could be more then one
preg_match_all('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^\r\n]*)/mi', $result, $ms);
// print_r($result);
$cookies = array();
foreach ($ms[1] as $m) {
    list($name, $value) = explode('=', $m, 2);
    $cookies[$name] = $value;
}
print_r($cookies);
```

Comment: thanks with this it prints the cookies but they are not set in my browser

Comment: Yes, true. The server (URL) trying to set cookies but can't, cos cookies go to CURL (in simple saying). So it's same with this (command line): `curl -v http://google.com/`. But if you open URL with your browser these cookies will be set on your browser.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "HTTP://URLHERE.COM");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, false);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
preg_match('/^Set-Cookie: (.*?);/m', curl_exec($ch), $m);
var_dump(parse_url($m[1]));
curl_close ( $ch );
echo $html;
```

Duplicate question pretty much from:
[how to get the cookies from a php curl into a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895786/how-to-get-the-cookies-from-a-php-curl-into-a-variable)

Comment: Thanks i seen that post i tried this and it didnt work it still not getting all the cookies and setting them for me.

Comment: provide us with an example of the code you're using and what it returns please

Comment: Im using the code above and $stuff_link[0] is set to a link which as cookies but when the curl run it doesnt load cookies

Comment: it returns this from using above code array(1) { ["path"]=> string(0) "" }