# How to retrieve particular header fields from a raw HTTP response?

Tags: php, http-headers

This is what `$result` returns :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: SERVER
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8
Connection: close
Expires: Tue, 26 Mar 2013 00:28:45 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Date: Tue, 26 Mar 2013 00:28:45 GMT
Content-Length: 290
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: KEY=isbgvigbiwsb124252525252; Domain=www.website.com; Expires=Tue, 26-Mar-13 02:28:44 GMT; Path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: session=12345566789:abc1231552662626262; Domain=www.website.com; Expires=Thu, 25-Apr-2013 00:28:43 GMT; Path=/


<login>
  <success>1</success>
  <player>
     <id>1234567</id>
     <AnotherId>123456</AnotherId>
     <email>email@email.com</email>
      <accountinformation>
          <id>123456</id>
          <name>namehere</name>
          <number>1234360</number>
       </accountinformation>  
   </player>
</login>
```

I want to retrieve the `KEY` cookie from the response. Currently my code is as follows

```
//a cURL function would be here
$result = curl_exec($ch); 

list($body, $split) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $result, 2);
$arr = explode("\r\n", $body);   

$start = explode(":", $arr[10]);    
$end = explode(";", $start[1]);
$INFO_I_NEED = $end[0];
```

What would be a simpler way of performing this action ? since it needs to be done 3/4 times for different parsing areas.

Comment: Write a method for it? Use a self-describing structure like XML?

Comment: What do you advise as such "method" ?

Comment: Can you give an example of the data you have in $result and what part you want in $INFO_I_NEED?

Comment: @Curtis Crewe When you copy and paste that code, what things change? Make those parameters in your method.

Comment: @Kara - done as requested

Comment: @CurtisCrewe Your question should reflect what you want to achieve and not what you’ve already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like [`preg_match_all`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) might be what you are looking for.  Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/895858/971556) as inspiration try:

```
preg_match_all('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^;]*)/mi', $result, $m);
```

You could then write a function like this:

```
function getCookies($result) {
    preg_match_all('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^;]*)/mi', $result, $m);
    return($m)
}

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$cookiesArray = getCookies($result);
```

The return value of the function will be an array of all the cookie values.  So `$cookiesArray` will hold:

```
array (
  0 => 'KEY=isbgvigbiwsb124252525252',
  1 => 'session=12345566789:abc1231552662626262',
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Put it inside a function so you can reuse when need be:

```
<?php
//a cURL function would be here
$result = curl_exec($ch); 

$INFO_I_NEED = myExplode($result);

function myExplode($data){

    list($body, $split) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $result, 2);
    $arr = explode("\r\n", $body);   

    $start = explode(":", $arr[10]);    
    $end = explode(";", $start[1]);

    return($end[0]);

}
?>
```