# PHP cURL Session not found / Session may have expired

Tags: php, session, cookies, curl

So I use cURL to get data from page 1, fetch info from it and store it in an array.   The next step is to load the next page, I do this by creating a new cURL with the same cookiejar and cookiefile.   I see the page 1 correctly but page 2 displays: Session not found. Session may have expired.  By looking at the header information I see that in page 1 it sets the cookie WCOOKIE=rd244o00000000000000000000ffff912c10f5o80.
In the headers of page 2 it sets the cookie WCOOKIE=rd244o00000000000000000000ffff912c10f6o80.
So this is why it thinks the session is expired, it doesn't load the cookie but the page tries to rewrite it.  So my question: What must I do to let page 2 load the cookie set by page 1 instead of trying to set a new cookie?

Additional information: 
the loading of the two pages both happens in one file (1.php) because I need to store both the data in 1 array, and you need the cookie from page 1 to be able to request page 2.

Both pages are set to use headers:

```
$headers[] = "Accept: */*";  
$headers[] = "Connection: Keep-Alive";  
$headers[] = "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";
```

Loading page 1:

```
$cSession = curl_init(); 
$tmpfname = dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt';
curl_setopt($cSession, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $tmpfname);
curl_setopt($cSession, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $tmpfname);
curl_setopt($cSession, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,  $headers);
curl_setopt ($cSession, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, TRUE);
```

Loading page 2:

```
$ch = curl_init ();
$tmpfname = dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $tmpfname);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $tmpfname);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,  $headers);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, TRUE);
```

This ain't all the settings but I'm guessing I have to change something in these lines, if more info is needed please let me know and i'll post them.
Help much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Okay I finally I fixed it thanks to this post [how to get the cookies from a php curl into a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895786/how-to-get-the-cookies-from-a-php-curl-into-a-variable). I post it here for other people having the same problem.
First I turned on CURLOPT_HEADER in request 1. Then I used this code to get the cookie:

```
preg_match('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^;]*)/mi', $result, $m);
parse_str($m[1], $cookies);
$cookie = $cookies['NAMEOFCOOKIEUNEEDHERE'];
```

So then I could pass this cookie on in request 2 by using this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'NAMEOFCOOKIEUNEEDHERE='.$cookie);
```

Hope this could help anyone