# How to read COOKIES from text file PHP

Tags: php, curl, cookies

I have used CURL with PHP, please check the below code

```
$cookie = "cookies.txt";
file_put_contents($cookie, "");
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

After that I opened the `cookies.txt` file, in that the cookies are stored.

Now how do I read that file to get required content.

I have tried to read the file using `readfile` `file_get_contents` but no use at all, these are just returning empty string.

Please help me out.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you need to read the cookie file?

Comment: Where are you set file_get_contents?

Comment: From that file i need to get 2 particular cookies and set that values with different cookie names.

Comment: I have set after `$response` line

    $get = file_get_contents($cookie);

Comment: Anyway, you should be able to read the file with `file_get_contents`, if you get an empty string, then the file is maybe empty?

Comment: Just add time() in file name.

Comment: But I am able to see the text in cookie.txt file @CharlotteDunois

Comment: I am not able to understand what you are saying. Can you be more clear @QuỳnhNguyễn

Comment: @SathvikChinnu Are you try file_get_contents("cookies.txt"); ?

Comment: Are you sure it's an empty string you get? Is error reporting enabled?

Comment: @SathvikChinnu It mean you can create more cookies file with another name by time() in file name

Comment: Does it work if you pause before reading? For example add `sleep(10)` (a 10 second pause) after the CURL before you try to read the file. Just for testing.

Comment: Yeah i am just readin it in this way only ` file_get_contents("cookies.txt");`

Comment: No even `sleep(10)` is not working still the same @BeetleJuice

Comment: No not working @BeetleJuice.. I think I may have doing some wrong. I will send the link contains complete code

Comment: Actually if I write `$cookie_text = file_get_contents("cookies.txt");` outside the `curl_close($ch);` code then it is working fine but I want to get the code before `curl_close($ch);`

Comment: As I wrote in my answer, CURL writes to the file only at the end of its session, so you won't be able to read the cookies from the file before you close the connection. In my answer I gave you an alternative approach though that should still work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CURL writes the cookies to file at the end of its session. Your problem could be that you're accessing the cookie file before CURL has written the cookies.

The possible fix is to end the CURL session *before* you try to read from the cookie file:

```
curl_easy_cleanup($ch);
...
$cookie_text = file_get_contents("cookies.txt");
```

[See the docs.](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_cleanup.html)

**As a clean alternative**, just grab the cookies from the response directly, without going through the `cookies.txt` file.  The code below will put the cookies in an array for you:

```
preg_match_all('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^;]*)/mi', $response, $matches);
$cookies = array();
foreach($matches[1] as $item) {
    parse_str($item, $cookie);
    $cookies = array_merge($cookies, $cookie);
}
```

Code taken from this [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895786/how-to-get-the-cookies-from-a-php-curl-into-a-variable):