# POST request from postman 4.2.2 to couchdb in localhost does not return cookie

Tags: cookies, couchdb, postman

I am sending a POST request to my local test_db (couchDB database):

```
POST http://localhost:1970/_session
```

using the following values in the body request:

```
x-www-form-urlencoded
name: admin
password: xxxxxx
```

the request executes correctly but in the response I do not get a cookie:

```
{
  "ok": true,
  "name": null,
  "roles": [
   "_admin",
   "dbadmin"
  ]
}
```

do you know why?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/api/server/authn.html#get--_session), the data returned is correct. The cookie is inside the response headers. Here's [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895786/how-to-get-the-cookies-from-a-php-curl-into-a-variable) of how to retrieve it with PHP.

[image: Couchdb document screen shot.]