# PHP - How to send data to remote form

Tags: php, forms, authorization

I need to send POST data to the remote form. I have a simple script...

```
$data['field1'] = '1';
$data['field2'] = '2';
$data['field3'] = '3';  

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.example.com/my-form.php?authToken=poWQyj2q");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

$output = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);

curl_close($ch);

echo $output;
```

... It would be work nice, but there is a problem with form URL - How you can see, there is some "authToken" value which changes each time a page is loaded. When it is incorrect, the form is sent, but not processed.

Any ideas how to solve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Request the page containing the form
2. [Extract the auth token from the DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)
3. (Presumably) store [the cookie value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895786/how-to-get-the-cookies-from-a-php-curl-into-a-variable)
4. Make your request but also include the auth token and the cookie