# How can i display all cookie values in PHP?

Tags: php, cookies

I'm trying to display all the cookie values of any REMOTE URL just like - http://www.cookie-checker.com/

Here what i'm thinking -

```
     $req = new HTTP_Request($url);
$req->setMethod(HTTP_REQUEST_METHOD_GET);
$req->sendRequest();
$cookies = $req->getResponseCookies();
print_r($cookies);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get the cookies from a php curl into a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895786/how-to-get-the-cookies-from-a-php-curl-into-a-variable)

Comment: that is exactly you do, read documentation https://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.http.http-request.cookie.php