# Getting data cookies from another page to the other using PHP

Tags: php

i have two sites http://domain1/getcookieshere.php && http://domain2/reqcookie/reqcookieshere.php.

I've echoed `$_COOKIE['cookie_name']` on `getcookieshere.php`. then on the `reqcookieshere.php` I've used  `$cookies = file_get_contents('http://ip/domain1/getcookieshere.php');`

then I echo the `$cookie`, but it does not return or display  on reqcookieshere.php.

any possible solution? thank you!

Comment: Cookies are not shared between domains by default. Have you enabled Cross-Origin-Request-Policy (CORS)?

Comment: @ObsidianAge Hi, can I ask if where will i put the headers? is it on the first getcookis.php or reqcookies.php? thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can't get cookie from another domain. 
I guess what you need is [CURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

```js
<?php
$ch = curl_init('http://www.google.com/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
preg_match_all('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^;]*)/mi', $result, $matches);
$cookies = array();
foreach($matches[1] as $item) {
    parse_str($item, $cookie);
    $cookies = array_merge($cookies, $cookie);
}
var_dump($cookies);
```

See this reference : [how to get the cookies from a php curl into a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895786/how-to-get-the-cookies-from-a-php-curl-into-a-variable)

Comment: it returns a blank array

Comment: Is this what you need? Can you access google directly? I try my snippet ok.