# How to get session cookies of a site?

Tags: php

I am trying to parse a website where I have to first the cookies and then pass to another request. In Python I can do the following:

```
session = requests.Session()
response = session.get('https://www.page.com')
cookies = response.cookies
response = session.get('https://www.page.com/part/1234', headers=headers,cookies=cookies)
print(response.text)
```

What options do I have available if I use the `file_get_contents` or `Requests` library?

I could not find it in [this](https://github.com/rmccue/Requests/) library.

Comment: Examples for using cookies in PHP: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895786/how-to-get-the-cookies-from-a-php-curl-into-a-variable or similar questions

Comment: @the_nuts so curl is the only option? I thought some lib or `file_get_contents` can here here.

Comment: file_get_contents returns only the body of the HTTP response, but the cookies are in the header

Comment: yeah there are a lot of libraries to perform http requests and handle them

Comment: @the_nuts Ok I did get how to capture cookies from a CURL request, how to exactly pass those captured cookies in another CURL request? should I save it in file or what?

Comment: Sadly even capturing cookies not working. The site is ASP.NET and CURL is not capturing ASP Session cookies.

Comment: You should understand how cookies work, the browser doesn't care what technology is behind the webserver, the cookies are just an instruction that he receives, and store... It will work for sure, now I can't write the code for you here...